# Url.Action has one object route value as null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pass two parameters to a controller in order to return a list of roles for the current user in a particular application. This list is then used for to autocomplete a search box.

My issue arises because one of the object route variables is always null in my Url.Action helper. The code is in a script on a partial view as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function roleFilter(element) {
        element.kendoAutoComplete({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "@Url.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Roles", new { userName = ViewBag.UserName, applicationName = ViewBag.ApplicationName })"
            }
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This part of the code is what is failing and giving a null value:

```
applicationName = ViewBag.ApplicationName
```

I know the ViewBag contains the correct values but it is empty in this script but I can pass it in code elsewhere on the page. if any one can help it would be very appreciated.

Full Partial View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BUUK.BSS.Models.Role>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource // Configure the grid data source
        .Ajax() // Specify that ajax binding is used
        .Read(read => read.Action("CurrentUserRoles_Read", "User",
            new
            {
                userName = ViewBag.UserName,
                applicationName = ViewBag.ApplicationName
            })) // Set the action method which will return the data in JSON format
            .PageSize(15)
     )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(role => role.RoleName)
            .Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("roleFilter"));
    })
          .Pageable() // Enable paging
          .Sortable() // Enable sorting
              .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                .Extra(false)

                .Messages(m => m.Info("Items with value equal to:")
                )
            ).Events(e => e.FilterMenuInit("filterMenuInit"))
        )

<p style="margin-top:5px;">
    @Html.ActionLink("Add Roles", "EditRoles", "User", new { applicationName =     ViewBag.ApplicationName, userName = ViewBag.UserName }, null)
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function roleFilter(element) {
        element.kendoAutoComplete({
             dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "@Url.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Roles", new { userName = ViewBag.UserName, applicationName = ViewBag.ApplicationName })"
            }
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Roles(string userName, string applicationName, string status)
    {
        var model = new List<Role>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Application.Applications, IRole> entry in Application.RoleMap)
        {
            if (entry.Key.ToString() == applicationName)
            {
                IRole role = entry.Value;
                model = role.GetUserRoles(userName);
            }
        }

        ViewBag.ApplicationName = applicationName;
        ViewBag.UserName = userName;
        ViewBag.Status = status;

        return View(model);
    }

public ActionResult FilterMenuCustomization_Roles(string userName, string applicationName)
    {
        var model = new List<Role>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Application.Applications, IRole> entry in Application.RoleMap)
        {
            if (entry.Key.ToString() == applicationName)
            {
                IRole role = entry.Value;
                model = role.GetUserRoles(userName);
            }
        }
        return Json(model.Select(e => e.RoleName).Distinct(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am happy to supply any other information that is required, Thanks again for any help.

**EDIT**

If I switch the order in which the parameters are written i.e.

```
read: "@Url.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Roles", new { applicationName = ViewBag.ApplicationName, userName = ViewBag.UserName })"
```

instead of as above. The `applicationName` passes correctly but the `userName` is `null` instead

Comment: What is the content of `ViewBag.ApplicationName` when it's output to the view? Can you debug it and see it's value? And what URL does it output to the page?

Comment: @DavidG The Content of `ViewBag.ApplicationName` in the view is `amadeus` when I debug in the Url.Action it says it is `null` but in other places the `ViewBag.Application`holds `Amadeus as expected` I am not sure what URL you are after?

Comment: Is it null for every part in the view or just in the `kendoAutoComplete` part?

Comment: @DavidG just the `KendoAutoComplete`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the url that is created by

```
 @Url.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Roles", new { userName = ViewBag.UserName, applicationName = ViewBag.ApplicationName })
```

in your JavaScript. It might be formatted incorrectly. Try:

```
"@Html.Raw(Url.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Roles", new { userName = ViewBag.UserName, applicationName = ViewBag.ApplicationName }))"
```

Comment: using `@Html.Raw` gives me the following runtime exception:`JavaScript critical error at line 68, column 33 in http://localhost:59933/User/Roles?userName=chris.blair&applicationName=Amadeus&status=Active\n\nSCRIPT5017: Syntax error in regular expression`

Comment: That looks like a JavaScript syntax error, and is not really MVC related.

Comment: Try this:
console.log('@Url.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Roles", new { userName = ViewBag.UserName, applicationName = ViewBag.ApplicationName })')

console.log('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Roles", new { userName = ViewBag.UserName, applicationName = ViewBag.ApplicationName }))')

and see if they are different

Comment: Just inside your <script> tag. It's only for debugging purposes

Comment: yes there is a difference the Url.action supplies: `/User/FilterMenuCustomization_Roles?userName=chris.blair&amp;applicationName=Amadeus` and the raw Url.Action supplies: `/User/FilterMenuCustomization_Roles?userName=chris.blair&applicationName=Amadeus` the first has `amp;` between the two root values. does this make a significant difference?

Comment: Yes, this is the issue I an referring to, the url is formatted incorrectly in JavaScript.
Again, wrapping the Url.Action in Html.Raw will solve your problem :)

Comment: I got the same error as before but after clearing the browsers cash  it works well. Thank you very much.